# I am creating mobile application on flutter but facing error of tflite library

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I am facing the below error I tried different version of tflite ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0 but facing same issue.
dependencies in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  tflite: ^2.1.1
  flutter_tts: ^3.6.3
  camera: ^0.10.3+2
```

Because my_app depends on tflite ^2.1.1 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

Comment: can you share your error message

Answer (score 0):

Use override dependency for packages to make sure every package make sure to get overrided dependency.
Mean if two of your packages depending upon different version of a single package, use that dependency as a override_dependency like:

```
name: angularApp
dependencies:
  angular:
    git:  'git@github.com:angular/angular.dart'
  third_party_angular_plugin: any
dependency_overrides:
  angular: ">=0.9.10"
```